# Not displayed background image

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am developing a component in vue.js and I have a problem that the picture is not displayed in the following tag:

```
<b-icon v-if="displayShowHistory && checkRole('showHistory')" class="backlight show-modal-icon" id="historyDoc" @click="showHistory"></b-icon>

.b-icon#historyDoc {
  background: url("../assets/history.png") center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 32px;
}
```

In this case, the image is displayed in the console with styles:
[image]

How to make the image appear correctly on the page? Nothing is displayed now.

Comment: Does the icon element have a height?

Comment: @Matt Dalzell, I did not set the height in the styles, only the width

Comment: Is `b-icon` part of a component library (e.g., `bootstrap-vue`)? Is your `v-if` condition true?

Answer (score 0):

Your background image's size is larger.
Add `background-size: cover;` property

Comment: it doesn't help in any way

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are missing the `height` css attribute.  Assuming that this is a block element, you would need that in addition to the width.  Otherwise, your element would have 0 height, effectively meaning that none of the background would show.

```
.b-icon#historyDoc {
  background: url("../assets/history.png") center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

If this is an inline element, you may need to add `display: block;` as well.